# Angularjs Select doesn't find value

Tags: angularjs

i've got this simple select in my view :

```
<select ng-model="test" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">Choisir</option>
    <option ng-repeat="cm in commercials|orderBy:'cm.commentaire'" value="{{cm.id_client}}">{{::cm.commentaire}} {{::cm.id_client}}</option>
```

I 've got this in my controler :

```
$scope.test=150;
```

Now , the html select is supposed to select the cm.id_client who's got the value equal to 150, but iot doesn't work.

The select shows correctly {{::cm.commentaire}} {{::cm.id_client}} but is not initilised with the 150

In my memory, it was working before in  other cases.
This is a sample of my select, showing the name and the most important {{::cm.id_client}}.

[image]

You can see that  there is a 150 in the list

I've also tryed to add track by cm.id_client, but still no luck

Comment: post what you have in commercials

Comment: There is nothing more intersting in commercials than the variables pictured,

Comment: It used to work in other cases really can't understand why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Use `ng-value` instead of `value`. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zHQfGOqFMkv2AbawFjhp) is a link for a working plunker

Comment: Ok , finally added ng-value and it works, only after clearing the navigator cache thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ng-repeat in "option", try to use "ng-options" in "select"

```
<select ng-options="cm.id_client as cm.commentaire+' '+cm.id_client for cm in commercials|orderBy:'cm.commentaire'" ng-model="test" class="form-control" required>
<option value="">Choisir</option>
</select>
```

note the format [a] as [b] for [c] in [d]

- [a] the real current value of this select, will bind to ng-model variable
- [b] the value that will display in dropdown list
- [c] item(or object) in current iteration
- [d] array of all option objects

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i will try  !